# Apply macro to any sheet in the same workbook

Tags: excel, vba, vba7

I have a bunch of sheets in the same workbook and I want to be able to click a button and run a Macro in the sheet I clicked the Macro Button.

This is one of my codes:

```
Sub PromoCC()  
PromoCC Macro  
    Sheets("Tipos de Proyecto").Select  
    Rows("3:69").Select  
    Range("Promoción_Nuevo_SKU_Compra_Item").Activate  
    Selection.Copy
```

I want to change this next line to be able to paste the copied data to the macro caller sheet

```
    **Sheets("General").Select**  
    Range("A4").Select  
    Selection.End(xlDown).Select  
    Selection.Insert  
    Shift:=xlDown  
    Range("C5").Select  
End Sub
```

I need a solution to the active sheet code, cause the "active sheet" after the data is copied is different to the macro caller sheet.

Comment: Note: [Avoid the use of Select](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/75794331/edit) in your code. Doing this should also solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

In your code, when the macro is called by clicking the button, you can record what sheet you are on and store the sheet name in a variable.

It can the be used later in your code.

Create the variables

```
Public CurrentWorkbook As String
Public CurrentSheet As String
```

Store a value in the variables

```
CurrentWorkbook = ActiveWorkbook.Name
CurrentSheet = ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Name
```

Then when you want to reference the stored values, use code like this:

```
Windows(CurrentWorkbook).Activate
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(CurrentSheet).Select
```

Putting it all together based on your code.
The code can be improved but this stays close to your existing code.

```
Option Explicit

Public CurrentWorkbook As String
Public CurrentSheet As String
'Create the variables

Sub PromoCC()
Dim lastrow As String
    CurrentWorkbook = ActiveWorkbook.Name
    CurrentSheet = ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Name
'Store a value in the variables

    Sheets("Tipos de Proyecto").Rows("3:69").Copy
'Copy the data

    Windows(CurrentWorkbook).Activate
    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(CurrentSheet).Select
'Reselect the stored variables
'Only needed if you have change workbook or worksheet in your code

    Sheets(CurrentSheet).Range("A" & Sheets(CurrentSheet).Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Select
'Go to the last row with data in column A in the calling worksheet
    ActiveCell.Offset(rowOffset:=1, columnOffset:=0).Activate
'Move down one row in Column A
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown
'Insert the copied data

    Range("C5").Select

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Robert, Si I'm trying to apply this solution but I've two errors. 1.- If I "Set" the CurrentWorkbook = ActiveWorkbook.Name" it pops up a "Compile error: Invalid outside procedure" And 2.- If I don't set it, then the same error pops up and highlight the "ActiveWorkbook" word. ¿Any ideas why?

Comment: The example code needs to be inside a procedure (Sub).  See the updated answer that has a full code example based on your code.